# Django get custom m2m field value

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

### Scenario:

I have lots of questions in a test bank, and some of them are similar. So I defined a custom m2m field that allow me to know the similarity of each two questions.

My models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    number = models.SmallIntegerField()
    question = models.TextField()
    related_q = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name='RelatedQuestion', 
                                       through='RelatedQuestion',
                                       symmetrical=False,
                                       blank=True)


class RelatedQuestion(models.Model):
    from_question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name="source+")
    to_question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name="destiny+")
    similarity = models.FloatField()
```

The similarity looks like below.
[image]

### Question

How can I get the similarity later on?

```
>>> Question.objects.get(pk=5757).related_q.first()
<Question: 100-1-1-1  下顎骨中最重要的力軌（trajectory）為何？ >

>>> Question.objects.get(pk=5757).related_q.first().id
1

>>> Question.objects.get(pk=5757).related_q.similarity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'similarity'

>>> Question.objects.get(pk=5757).related_q.first().similarity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'similarity'

>>> Question.objects.get(pk=5757).RelatedQuestion_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'RelatedQuestion_set'

>>> Question.objects.get(pk=5757).RelatedQuestion.similarity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'similarity'
```

Comment: `similarity` is a field of `RelatedQuestion` instead of `Question`. You can query on `RelatedQuestion`.

Comment: @stamaimer I had updated my post, see the last two line on `RelatedQuestion`. But still cannot work.

Comment: The exception message is very clear. You get `RelatedQuestion_set` on `Question` and `RelatedQuestion` on `ManyRelatedManager `. I'm not familiar `Django`. I guess the query might be `QuestionRelated.objects.get(from_question_id=5757).first().similarity`.

Comment: @stamaimer Thank you, It works! `RelatedQuestion.objects.filter(from_question_id=484).first().similarity
`

Answer (score 1):

The `similarity` field is on `RelatedQuestion` while you're trying to access it on a `Question`. You also can't get it via the field because there are potentially many questions that are related; Which one would it choose to return the similarity value from?

Additionally, you can't access the "through" model via the manager, which is why you're getting errors on the `ManyRelatedManager`.

You can access the through model via a `_set` reverse lookup.

```
Question.objects.get(pk=5757).source_set.first().similarity
```

**NOTE:** I can't test the above code as I write this, so take it with a grain of salt as it points you in the right direction.

Comment: How to use the `_set` reverse lookup? I tried `Question.objects.get(pk=5757).RelatedQuestion_set` and I got 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'RelatedQuestion_set'
`

Comment: It seems that I cannot access `RelatedQuestion` from `Question`..., is it because this is a `self` m2m field?